# Save Game Using JSON in Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I create a simple Save Game system in Unity using Unity's JSON Serialization. My Save Game is pretty simple, I am only saving the position of my character and loading it.

The save game works fine, in-game. When I launch the game and click 'Save' the game is saved and the JSON file is updated with my players position. When I click 'Load' the game loads fine and my player is moved to the previously saved position.

However my issue is that whenever I shut down the game and relaunch it, the 'Load' function just resets my character to the position at which I spawn it at. It does not load the character at my previously saved position in the last game.

Now for my code. I have an Actor class which hold my actor's data:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class Actor : MonoBehaviour
{

    public ActorData data = new ActorData(); // to store our data

    public void StoreData() // for storing our data
    {
        data.pos = transform.position;
    }

    public void LoadData() // for loadinjg our data
    {
        transform.position = data.pos;
    }

    public void ApplyData()
    {
        SaveData.AddActorData(data);
    }

    void OnEnable() // to enable the save/load to avoid hanging
    {
        SaveData.OnLoaded += LoadData;
        SaveData.OnBeforeSave += StoreData;
        SaveData.OnBeforeSave += ApplyData;
    }

    void OnDisable() // to disable the save/load to avoid hanging
    {
        SaveData.OnLoaded -= LoadData;
        SaveData.OnBeforeSave -= StoreData;
        SaveData.OnBeforeSave -= ApplyData;
    }
}

[Serializable] // for storing in JSON
public class ActorData // our players attributes in JSON
{
    public Vector3 pos;
}
```

I also have an ActorContainer to hold the data for different players:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

[Serializable]
public class ActorContainer
{

    // To store our different actors data
    public List<ActorData> actors = new List<ActorData>();
}
```

I have a SaveData class which performs my Serialization:

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

public class SaveData
{

    // every actos will be sorted in this actor container when loading the game
    public static ActorContainer actorContainer = new ActorContainer(); // static so that we dont have to recreacte savedata everytime

    public delegate void SerializeAction();
    public static event SerializeAction OnLoaded; // happens after loading
    public static event SerializeAction OnBeforeSave; // right before saving

    public static void Load(string path) // where the load is
    {
        actorContainer = LoadActors(path);

        OnLoaded();

        ClearActorList(); // so that there's no duplicates
    }

    public static void Save(string path, ActorContainer actors)
    {
        OnBeforeSave(); // to throw of the data that was in OnBeforeSave

        SaveActors(path, actors); // store all of our actors as json in the file

        ClearActorList(); // clear the list so that the next time we save theres no duplicates
    }

    public static void AddActorData(ActorData data)
    {
        actorContainer.actors.Add(data);
    }

    public static void ClearActorList() // to avoid duplicate data
    {
        actorContainer.actors.Clear(); // access actors and clear it
    }

    private static ActorContainer LoadActors(string path) // path to the JSON
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText(path); // loading all the text out of the file into a string, assuming the text is all JSON

        return JsonUtility.FromJson<ActorContainer>(json); // parse the JSON into an ActorContainer type and return in the LoadActors
    }

    private static void SaveActors(string path, ActorContainer actors) // where to save and the actors to save
    {
        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(actors);

        StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path); // if file doesnt exist, make the file in the specified path
        sw.Close();

        File.WriteAllText(path, json); // fill the file with the data(json)
    }
}
```

Lastly I have a GameController class which acts as a communicator with Unity:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{ // to tell unity what it has to do, a communicator to be used with unity

    // trigger buttons
    public Button saveButton;
    public Button loadButton;

    private static string dataPath = string.Empty;

    void Awake()
    {
        dataPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "actors.json"); // persistentDataPath unity save game path, actors.json name of the file containing actors 
    }

    // for button
    public void Save()
    {
        SaveData.Save(dataPath, SaveData.actorContainer);
    }

    // for button 
    public void Load()
    {
        SaveData.Load(dataPath);
    }
}
```

My JSON file actors.json contains the following:

> {"actors":[{"pos":{"x":419.6240539550781,"y":5.0189208984375,"z":0.0}}]}

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You never assign the loaded Value to `data.pos` in `Actor.cs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is simply, you never assign the loaded Value from the JSON to `data.pos` in `Actor.cs`. Instead you load it from the public field `ActorData data`, which hasn't changed.

If i can see this right you have to change in `Actor.cs` following:

```
using System.Linq;

// ..

public void LoadData() 
{
    // guessing you will implementing an identifier for the separate actors later..
    var currentActor = SaveData.actorContainer.First();
    transform.position = currentActor.pos;

    // also set the loaded data to the field
    data = currentActor;
}

// ..
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct! Thank you :)

Comment: @arjwolf Glad i could help! :D